# select vertices based on name

Tags: python, igraph

I create a graph and add nodes using the following code.

```
g = Graph()
g.add_vertices(3)
g.vs["name"] = ["ABC","ABCD","ACD"]
```

I want to select vertices from the graph where the vertices name contain 'AB'. From the above graph, it should return "ABC" and "ABCD". Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `list(filter(lambda x:return x.startswith('AB'),g.vs["name"]))` It will give you the list of nodes starting with AB.

Comment: expression expected. 'return' outside of function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have not specified the number of nodes the graph will contain, I will assume you do not need to scale. You can use [List Comprehension](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) :

```
a = ["ABC","ABCD","ACD"] #List of vertices
#or in your case a = g.vs['name']

b = ["AB"]               #Pattern to be matched

match =[vert for patt in b for vert in a if patt in vert]

print match
#['ABC', 'ABCD']
```